# Symbols undefined for RtMidi on OS X?

Tags: c++, g++

I'm having some trouble compiling a basic program using RtMidi on OS X. I initially tried using XCode and adding the library as a target, then I tried a simpler compilation using g++. The same errors were returned in each instance.

Here's the command and output:

```
$ g++ -Wall -D __MACOSX_CORE__ -o midiprobe midiprobe.cpp -framework CoreAudio -framework CoreFoundation -lpthread

Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "RtMidiIn::RtMidiIn(RtMidi::Api, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >, unsigned int)", referenced from:
  _main in midiprobe-d2b0ea.o
  "RtMidiOut::RtMidiOut(RtMidi::Api, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >)", referenced from:
  _main in midiprobe-d2b0ea.o
  ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
```

This is my first time using a library in this manner, so some pointers in the right direction would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I’m having the same issue. Were you able to solve this?